# Add VAR as attribute name or description

Tags: jquery, var, wai-aria

I am calling a h4 text to use as the aria-label on a checkbox. Not the best way, however, I it is the only option I have on this project. I cab't get the variable to insert in the aria-label.

```
var prodname = $(".checkbox").closest("tr").find("td.product-shortdesc h4").text();
    console.log(prodname);
        $("td.select .checkbox").attr("aria-label", "'' +prodname+ '");
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that last line, it should be

`$("td.select .checkbox").attr("aria-label", prodname);`

Comment: Make sure to +1 my answer, I'm trying to get enough Reputation to add comments.

Comment: Thanks! Good luck on your project.

Comment: Thanks, about to ask another question :-)

Comment: This adds all the h4 text to each .checkbox. Is there a way so each h4 text is added to its associated.checkbox label?